# What is the difference between .NET remoting and WCF/TCP for local/LAN communication?

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-remoting

OK, so I know that [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx) is supposed to replace [dotNET remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), yet I seem to fail to really grasp if WCF is a full replacement with more options, or if .NET remoting offers some features that are missing from WCF?

As the title hints at, I do not need any of that Web* stuff. The use case is having a C# desktop application expose an RPC-ish interface to make it possible for other programs to communicate with / control the application. Number of possible clients is probably < 10 and communication is exclusively local network.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703720/net-remoting-over-wcf) that asks for something similar, but [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452268/remoting-or-wcf-for-new-development-between-two-net-apps-on-the-same-machine-u) seems to imply that .NET-remoting can in fact be used in ways that WCF does not offer.

Comment: It's not "supposed to replace" remoting, it replaced it four years ago.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET Remoting vs. Web Services vs. Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507862/net-remoting-vs-web-services-vs-windows-communication-foundation-wcf)

Comment: WCF is pretty easy to develop with and seems to be robust enough to tackle any communication you need. I wouldn't bother with remoting IMO..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use WCF with the self-hosted option (within the desktop application). Expose net.tcp binary endpoints assuming all other clients are .NET.

Check the sample "Form Host" on the iDesign downloads page:  http://www.idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=5&tabid=11

Answer (score 4):

There's no concept of "marshal by reference" in WCF, by design. Whether marshal-by-reference is ever a good idea is another matter, but regardless it's a major .NET Remoting feature that doesn't exist in WCF.

Comment: Does this mean every bit of communication involves copying objects over (like Marshall-by-value), or does it mean you just don't need to worry about specifying ": MarshallByRefObject" or does it mean something else altogether?

Comment: Yes, all communication in WCF involves copying/serialization.

Comment: OK, then, upvoted this and downvoted the false answer about it being a full replacement. By the way, one scenario that Microsoft never fully solved, but is partially solved (REST calls only) by MarshallByRefObject and AppDomains, is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160118/net-https-requests-with-different-security-protocols-across-threads

Answer (score 1):

WCF is full replacement for .net remoting. Your scenario is perfectly valid for WCF. You will easily complete it after reading few tutorials. All the mentioned use cases are controversial, I see no reason in using remoting nowadays.

Comment: WCF is not a full replacement; as Max Strini mentioned, it doesn't have marshal-by-ref.